# Как подсветить фразу на html странице php?

Tags: php

Есть html страница:

```
<p> какой-то текст найди </p> <p> меня еще какой-то текст </p>
```

И есть фраза

```
"найди меня"
```

Требуется подсветить ее на данной странице.
Фраза может пересекаться с любыми тегами, как в примере.

Как вариант должно получиться что-то типа такого:

```
<p> 
    какой-то текст <span class="red">найди</span> 
</p> 
<p> 
    <span class="red">меня</span> еще какой-то текст
</p>
```

Как это сделать средствам php?

Comment: PHP это язык программирования, специально разработанный для написания web-приложений (сценариев), исполняющихся на Web-сервере. А CSS - формальный язык описания внешнего вида документа, написанного с использованием языка разметки. Может быть, вам стоит подумать о стилях?

Comment: Меня интересует алгоритм поиска этих вхождений с последующим обрамлением в соответствующие теги

Comment: тут намного прое будет использовать JS

Comment: Покажите пример на js

Comment: ну или ищите в строке(вес документ) подстроку что начинается на найди и кончается на меня..и проверку делаете чтоб между нимим біло максимум n символов..(возможно между ними еще слова).. ну или проверку на тэги делаете..короче регулярки в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений, вот только искать будет только одно слово...

```
function search_replace($beginText,$search){
    $patterns = "/(".$search.")+/iu"; 
    $replace = "<span style='color:red'><em>$1</em></span>";// На что заменить
    $endText = PREG_REPLACE($patterns,$replace,$beginText);// Замена
    return $endText;
}
echo(searhh_replase("<p> какой-то текст найди </p> <p> меня еще какой-то текст </p>","найди"))
```

Comment: Это не решение моей проблемы. Фразу не найдет

Comment: Если сплитовать фразу по словам и каждый раз в цикле подавать на вход этой функции строку с поиском предыдущего слова, должно получиться

Comment: не совсем понял, можно код?

Answer (score 0):

Если нигде не ошибся, то должно работать

```php
$text = 'Длинный текст с тегами';
$match = 'найди меня';
$matchPos = 0;
$opentag = false;
$positions = [];
$curPos = [];
$startPos = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
  switch ($text[$i]) {
    case '<':
      if ($matchPos > 0)
        $curPos[] = [$startPos, $i];
      $opentag = true;
      break;
    case '>':
      if ($matchPos > 0)
        $startPos = $i;
      $opentag = false;
      break;
    default:
      if (!$opentag) {
        if ($text[$i] === $match[$matchPos]) {
          if ($matchPos === 0)
            $startPos = $i;
          else if ($matchPos === strlen($match) - 1) {
            $curPos[] = [$startPos, $i];
            $positions[] = $curPos;
            $curPos = [];
            $matchPos = 0;
          }
          $matchPos++;
        } else {
          $curPos = [];
          $matchPos = 0;
        }
      }
  }
}

for ($i = count(positions) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  for ($j = count(positions[i]) -  1; $j >= 0; $j--} {
    $text = substr_replace($text, '</span>', $positions[$i][$j][1]);
    $text = substr_replace($text, '<span class="selected">', $positions[$i][$j][0]);
}
```